# Spring Cloud Stream - Overriding Error handler

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a multi-binder spring cloud stream application and I have implementation exactly similar to the one explained in the documentation here at [Retry With the RabbitMQ Binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#retry-with-the-rabbitmq-binder.)

I intend to retry configured amount of times and eventually give up.

BUT

if errors are like the one below, it doesn't even get into the listener code for me to apply the `x-death` count logic. So the question is that how do I give up on messages with deserialisation and message conversion errors:

```
2018-09-06 16:41:11.889 ERROR [data-connector,671345aea4270626,48dd1100d9e332f9,false] 8866 --- [rdedStarGroup-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.ducation.connector.event.domain.AwardResource] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[369], headers={amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup, amqp_redelivered=false, notificationType=AwardResource, spanTraceId=671345aea4270626, spanId=671345aea4270626, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[671345aea4270626], spanId=[671345aea4270626], spanSampled=[0]}, x-first-death-exchange=outcome.awardedStar, X-B3-SpanId=671345aea4270626, x-death=[{reason=expired, count=65, exchange=DLX, routing-keys=[outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup], time=Thu Sep 06 16:21:21 GST 2018, queue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup.dlq}, {reason=rejected, count=65, exchange=outcome.awardedStar, routing-keys=[#], time=Thu Sep 06 16:21:16 GST 2018, queue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup}], x-first-death-reason=rejected, X-B3-Sampled=0, x-first-death-queue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup, X-B3-TraceId=671345aea4270626, id=865fe31f-8cb4-fab1-ce1f-7673e741ac48, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-Mz8gBRwIdx6czW6JCox2-w, spanSampled=0, contentType=application/plain, timestamp=1536237671843}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[369], headers={amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup, amqp_redelivered=false, notificationType=AwardResource, spanTraceId=671345aea4270626, spanId=671345aea4270626, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[671345aea4270626], spanId=[48dd1100d9e332f9], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[671345aea4270626], X-B3-SpanId=[48dd1100d9e332f9], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[671345aea4270626], spanParentSpanId=[671345aea4270626], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, x-first-death-exchange=outcome.awardedStar, X-B3-SpanId=671345aea4270626, x-death=[{reason=expired, count=65, exchange=DLX, routing-keys=[outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup], time=Thu Sep 06 16:21:21 GST 2018, queue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup.dlq}, {reason=rejected, count=65, exchange=outcome.awardedStar, routing-keys=[#], time=Thu Sep 06 16:21:16 GST 2018, queue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup}], x-first-death-reason=rejected, X-B3-Sampled=0, x-first-death-queue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup, X-B3-TraceId=671345aea4270626, id=865fe31f-8cb4-fab1-ce1f-7673e741ac48, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-Mz8gBRwIdx6czW6JCox2-w, spanSampled=0, contentType=application/plain, timestamp=1536237671843}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:144)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:116)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:109)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:165)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.java:87)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$600(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:207)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:817)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:801)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018-09-06 16:41:11.900  WARN [data-connector,,,] 8866 --- [rdedStarGroup-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1417) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1337) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:817) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:801) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.ducation.connector.event.domain.AwardResource] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[369], headers={amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup, amqp_redelivered=false, notificationType=AwardResource, spanTraceId=671345aea4270626, spanId=671345aea4270626, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[671345aea4270626], spanId=[671345aea4270626], spanSampled=[0]}, x-first-death-exchange=outcome.awardedStar, X-B3-SpanId=671345aea4270626, x-death=[{reason=expired, count=65, exchange=DLX, routing-keys=[outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup], time=Thu Sep 06 16:21:21 GST 2018, queue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup.dlq}, {reason=rejected, count=65, exchange=outcome.awardedStar, routing-keys=[#], time=Thu Sep 06 16:21:16 GST 2018, queue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup}], x-first-death-reason=rejected, X-B3-Sampled=0, x-first-death-queue=outcome.awardedStar.dataConnectorAwardedStarGroup, X-B3-TraceId=671345aea4270626, id=865fe31f-8cb4-fab1-ce1f-7673e741ac48, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-Mz8gBRwIdx6czW6JCox2-w, spanSampled=0, contentType=application/plain, timestamp=1536237671843}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:144) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:165) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.java:87) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$600(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:60) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:240) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:207) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1414) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

NOTE: I know the error itself and why its caused. It is intentional to test the `x-death` logic.

If my expectation is not possible, what is the best practice to catch such exceptions to prevent the application from retrying infinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal scenario, `MessageConversionException`s are treated as fatal (irrecoverable) and will never be requeued, but they will go to the DLQ, if configured.

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#exception-handling) for a list of such exceptions.

However, since you are re-routing DLQ messages back to the original queue, this is defeating the "fatal" nature of these errors.

I think the only practical work-around is to use `republishToDlq` and instead of routing the dead-letters to the original queue, expire them to another queue and have another listener on that queue (raw data, no conversion) and filter out the messages with this exception in the header while forwarding others to the original queue.

But I'll open an issue against the framework.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-833

**EDIT**

Here's a Spring Cloud Stream application that uses the two DLQs approach to discard irrecoverable messages...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(So52209397Application.Channels.class)
public class So52209397Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So52209397Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            template.convertAndSend("foo.group", "{\"bar\":\"baz\"}", m -> {
                m.getMessageProperties().setContentType("application/json");
                return m;
            }); // good
            template.convertAndSend("foo.group", "junk", m -> {
                m.getMessageProperties().setContentType("application/json");
                return m;
            });
        };
    }

    boolean first = true;

    @StreamListener("input")
    public void listen(Foo foo, @Header(value = "x-death", required = false) List<Map<?, ?>> xDeath) {
        System.out.println(foo);
        if (xDeath == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail first time (with retries)");
        }
        System.out.println(xDeath);
    }

    @StreamListener("inputDlq")
    public void listen(byte[] failed, @Header(RepublishMessageRecoverer.X_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE) LongString stackTrace) {
        System.out.println("StreamErrorHander: " + new String(failed));
        if (stackTrace.toString().contains("MessageConversionException")) { // should add other fatal errors here too
            System.out.println("Discarding message");
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Good exception; sending back to original queue");
        }
    }

    public interface Channels {

        @Input
        public MessageChannel input();

        @Input
        public MessageChannel inputDlq();

    }

    public static class Foo {

        private String bar;

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=group

# dead letters go to the default DLX/rk - DLX/foo.group
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-ttl=5000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.republish-to-dlq=true


# Raw consumer for failures
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputDlq.destination=DLX
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputDlq.group=foo.group.dlq

# disable retry for dlq listener
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputDlq.consumer.max-attempts=1

# dead letters are sent to DLX/foo.group.dlq.dlq
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.inputDlq.consumer.exchange-type=direct
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.inputDlq.consumer.ttl=5000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.inputDlq.consumer.queue-name-group-only=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.inputDlq.consumer.binding-routing-key=foo.group
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.inputDlq.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true

# foo.group.dlq.dlq routes expiries back to main queue via default exchange (could also be foo)
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.inputDlq.consumer.dlq-dead-letter-exchange=
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.inputDlq.consumer.dlq-dead-letter-routing-key=foo.group

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.inputDlq.consumer.dlq-ttl=1
```

Bottom line is the main consumer dead-letters everything to the `.dlq` which is consumed by the "raw" listener, which discards fatal errors and dead-letters "good" failures to the `...dlq.dlq`. This one has a short TTL and re-routes back to the main queue.

```
Foo [bar=baz]
Foo [bar=baz]
Foo [bar=baz]
...
StreamErrorHander: {"bar":"baz"}
...
StreamErrorHander: junk
Discarding message
Foo [bar=baz]
[{reason=expired, count=1, exchange=DLX, routing-keys=[foo.group.dlq]...
```

Comment: Based on your advice, apart from setting `republishToDlq` to `true` I need to set `deadLetterRoutingKey` to `DLX.anotherQueueGroup`? I am also setting the `bindings.anotherQueue.destination` to `DLX`. Am I headed in the right direction? The problem I am seeing with this config is that when application starts, my dead letter queue has two routing keys (I see in RabbitMQ admin console) e.g. `originalExchange.originalQueue.group` as well as `DLX.anotherQueueGroup` and no queue named `DLX.anotherQueueGroup` has been created...

Comment: I will try to find some time to put an example together.

Comment: See the edit to my answer; in the next version, this will be handled automatically due to AMQP-833.

Comment: thats very useful. Cheers.